# To comment out matches in Vim - independent on comment leader?

Tags: regex, vim, comments

I want to comment out lines in some code I have.  I have different kinds of codes, and they use different comment leaders.  E.g. in latex: '%', in Fortran 90: '!' and in python: '#'.  I want to do a substitute command that looks something like this:

```
:g/<search-string>/s/^/<add-comment-leader-here>/
```

If this is possible, I could also make a command in Vim that automatically commented out the selected text.  Something like this:

```
vmap <z> :'<,'>s/^/<add-comment-leader-here>/
```

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Enhanced Commentify](http://kotka.de/projects/enhancedcommentify/index.html): I think this does what you want: it determines the comment leader based on the file type.

If you want to do it yourself, the easiest way would be to define a mapping that uses `exec` to build a command and include a variable that is set in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` and other ftplugin files.  Alternatively, just add the same mapping (with a different leader) to each ftplugin file.

Comment: If you are using EnhancedCommentify, you should be able to do a generic
:g/<pattern>/exe "normal \<Plug>Comment" -- whatever the current filetype is.

Comment: If the link is still broken, you can try this mirror: https://github.com/vim-scripts/EnhCommentify.vim

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't seen it already, you may be interested in the [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) Vim plugin.

Comment: Do you have any comments about the differences between NERD Commenter and Enhanced Commentify? It seems both do something like what I want to do ... (and thanks for the tip, by the way!)

Comment: EnhancedCommentify is much more older and has always fulfilled my needs. In the end, I never felt the need to test the challenger.